Set checkbox indicator width or bg color within custom QStyledItemDelegate.paint()
I have a QTableView, and a custom QStyledItemDelegate for some of the columns so that they display a centered checkbox. It works, but the checkbox's indicator (the border, basically) is thin and hard to see against the background:

I'd like to make the indicator thicker. If that's not possible, setting the background color so that it stands out a bit more from the background would be better than nothing.
I'm a bit lost in the delegate/qstyle/qpalette/qrect meander. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's my code:
    def paint(self,
              painter: QtGui.QPainter,
              option: QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem,
              proxy_index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        self.initStyleOption(option, proxy_index)

        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style() if widget else QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        style.drawPrimitive(
            style.PE_PanelItemViewItem,
            option,
            painter,
            option.widget
        )

        rect = style.subElementRect(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_CheckBoxIndicator,
            option,
            widget=option.widget
        )

        option.rect = style.alignedRect(
            option.direction,
            Qt.AlignCenter,
            rect.size(),
            option.rect
        )

        proxy_model = proxy_index.model()
        source_model = proxy_model.sourceModel()
        source_index = proxy_model.mapToSource(proxy_index)

        item = source_model.itemFromIndex(source_index)
        option.state = style.State_On if item.checked else style.State_Off

        style.drawPrimitive(
            style.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck,
            option,
            painter,
            widget=option.widget
        )

I looked through all the abovementioned docs but nothing specifically stood out as the solution. I also set the QTableView's style sheet to QCheckbox::indicator {border: 1px solid <some color>;} but that didn't help.

Is that dark palette caused by the dark mode of the OS or set through stylesheet? What is the standard appearance (without the delegate) of the check indicator? Note that it's not clear what that checked attribute is, but in order to properly use the standard check behavior you should use the item's setCheckState().

The issue isn't the check behavior. It's the appearance of the checkbox.

I know that, I pointed out that aspect so that you could properly verify the standard painting behavior with the default implementation. Please answer the questions above.
